# How to append to bytes in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some `bytes`.

```
b'\x01\x02\x03'
```

And an `int` in range 0..255.

```
5
```

Now I want to append the `int` to the `bytes` like this:

```
b'\x01\x02\x03\x05'
```

How to do it? There is no `append` method in `bytes`. I don't even know how to make the integer become a single byte.

```
>>> bytes(5)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`bytes` is immutable. Use `bytearray`.

```
xs = bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03')
xs.append(5)
```

Comment: Note that `bytearray` can only store integers in range 0-256. Though in this case OP is only concerned with the same range. :-)

Comment: The `bytearray` has the `.extend` method to add more bytes at once like `xs.extend(b'\x11\x22\x33')`.

Comment: @Ashwini, (0-255)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary What else would be expected to fit into one byte?

Answer (score 28):

First of all passing an integer(say `n`) to `bytes()` simply returns an bytes string of `n` length with null bytes. So, that's not what you want here:

Either you can do:

```
>>> bytes([5]) #This will work only for range 0-256.
b'\x05'
```

Or:

```
>>> bytes(chr(5), 'ascii')
b'\x05'
```

As [@simonzack already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001435/4298200), bytes are immutable, so to update (or better say re-assign) its value, you need to use the `+=` operator.

```
>>> s = b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> s += bytes([5])     #or s = s + bytes([5])
>>> s
b'\x01\x02\x03\x05'

>>> s = b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> s += bytes(chr(5), 'ascii')   ##or s = s + bytes(chr(5), 'ascii')
>>> s
b'\x01\x02\x03\x05'
```

Help on `bytes()`:

```
>>> print(bytes.__doc__)
bytes(iterable_of_ints) -> bytes
bytes(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytes
bytes(bytes_or_buffer) -> immutable copy of bytes_or_buffer
bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes
bytes() -> empty bytes object

Construct an immutable array of bytes from:
  - an iterable yielding integers in range(256)
  - a text string encoded using the specified encoding
  - any object implementing the buffer API.
  - an integer
```

Or go for the mutable `bytearray` if you need a mutable object and you're only concerned with the integers in range 0-256.

Comment: Both solutions can be optimized by using `bytes((5,))` instead of the first one and `(5).to_bytes(1, "little")` for the second one. `int.to_bytes()` can be used to get longer byte sequences in the specified order from an integer of arbitrary size.

Comment: FWIW, a byte is 0..255, not 0..256

Comment: +1 for mentioning the += operator, i dont know why .append() only works on integers and doesn't take a bytes or another bytearray object, how infuriating

Comment: @mgrandi use .extend() and not +=