# How to read a binary file and append them to a new file?

Tags: python, byte

I read data from a file as binary data like

```
with open(filename, "rb") as filein:
    content = filein.read()
print(type(content[0]))
```

and I expected the data type of the data read to be `byte`, but I get `int`.

How to read data from a file as type `byte` (i.e. the python structure where I put a "b" in from of i like

```
mybyte = b"bytes"
```

so I can "add" them to other byte strings?

What I actually want to do is essentially this:

```
# Read the complete(!) content of the file
with open(filename, "rb") as filein:
    content = filein.read()

# Create new content, where I manipulate some single bytes
# For simplicity this is not shown here
new_content = b""
for byte in content:
    # some manipulating of single bytes, omitted for simplicity
    new_content += byte

# Write the modified content again to a new file
# In this very example, it should replicate the exact same file
with open(filename + "-changed", "wb") as fileout:
    fileout.write(new_content)
```

But here I get an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "break_software.py", line 29, in <module>
    new_content += byte
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

Comment: Python doesn't have a byte data type. It has byte strings, and the elements of byte strings are integers.

Comment: Incorrect, try `print(type(b""))`.

Comment: That's `bytes`, which is a byte string.

Comment: Yes that is what I expect to read from a file

Comment: Then check `type(content)`. `type(content[0])` is analogous to `type(b"abc"[0])` (since `b""` is empty)

Comment: You seem to be assuming that since the elements of strings are 1-character strings, the elements of byte strings will be 1-byte byte strings. They didn't repeat that mistake.

Comment: I updated the question with what I actually want to do

Comment: Are you asking how to append to a `bytes`? If so please update your title and consider the following duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/27001419/843953

Comment: Here I get then an error `TypeError: can't concat int to bytearray`.

Comment: [Weird](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6JYwVYhqbIkNbGoKLFSI0k9psLAEIiNgNhYXZOrolgvsaAgNS9Fw1STq6AoM69Eo6JY8/9/AA)

Comment: Ah sorry, when I use `new_content.append(..)` then it is working. I must not use `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `bytes` works in `python`, consider that

```
mybyte = b"bytes"
print(mybyte[0])  # 98
print(type(mybyte[0]))  # <class 'int'>
```

Comment: So how can I read the content of a file as "bytes"?

Comment: @Alex `content` is a `bytes` object.

Comment: You could use `filein.read(1)` to read 1 byte at a time.